# Unable to sync couchbase view in pouchdb using couchbase sync gateway

Tags: couchbase, pouchdb, couchbase-view, couchbase-sync-gateway

I am trying to get couchbase view result in pouchdb,but pouchdb unable to sync when i tried this code :

remoteDatabase url is(sync gateway url)=http://localhost:4984/sync_gateway

```
database.replicate.from(remoteDatabase, {
     live: true,
     retry: true,
     filter: '_view',
     view: '_design/dev_Test/_views/Test1'
});
```

It doesnt replicate anything. I want to replicate view as In couchbase I have  documents with 100+ fields but in pouch I want only few fields,for that I have created view in couchbase and trying to replicate in pouchdb. 
Thanks in advance